# What do you call a prism / cylinder with the bases being only a sector or semicircle?

Tags: polygons

I see some references about prisms use a example of a sector as a base in the problems. But by definitions, prisms are suppose to not have bases which aren't polygons. This is why cylinders are not considered prisms, or at least you avoid calling cylinders a prism with a circular base. So how do you call a prism or cylinder if the base is not a circle but not a polygon either? It just feels weird using the term sector prism.